# how to get ReTweet of Twitter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, twitter

i am using `string TWITTERFEEDURL = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/xxx.xml?count=4";` to get Tweets.
user_timeline = Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted by the authenticating user.

i want to get my ReTweets too. what i should use for that?? do i need be authenticated for that?

Comment: it's not necessary to add "asp.net c#" to your title. We've got tags for those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newtwitter has an [API method](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/twitter-development-talk/zcNK54ojULg/rqmau1XD4HYJ) to get retweets by a user. You would perform a GET request to `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_by_user.xml?screen_name=xyz`

You should also update your existing request to use the correct URL and API version as specified in the [documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline).